# roslaunch sick_tim551_2050001

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
After catkin_make of tim_sick branch indigo
and after  run roscore
and after plugged sick_timm551 by USB

I try to launch this :
roslaunch sick_tim551_2050001 ~/catkin_ws/src/sick_tim/launch/sick_tim.launch

I have this :

[/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/sick_tim/launch/sick_tim.launch] is neither a launch file in package [sick_tim551_2050001] nor is [sick_tim551_2050001] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I have not log file into .ros/log folder

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204266/roslaunch-sick_tim551_2050001/) by [colin-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/21781/colin-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arguments for roslaunch are **either** a package and a launch file name, **or** the path to a launch file. **Not both**

Try with either the package and launch file name:

```
roslaunch sick_tim sick_tim551_2050001.launch
```

**OR** the full path:

```
roslaunch ~/catkin_ws/src/sick_tim/launch/sick_tim.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-03-17**:
Just for future reference: This should be `roslaunch sick_tim sick_tim551_2050001.launch`.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-18**:
Thanks! Updated my answer with the corrected version.